# Accessing a List of Maps has different behavior depending on the index

Tags: arrays, arraylist, groovy

Assuming we have a List of Maps in Groovy I noticed a strange behavior today.

```
List listOfMap = [[1:'b'], [1: 'c']]
println listOfMap[1]

>>> [1: c]
```

This makes sense to me, as I would expect to get the second element from the list.

If I now have Maps from String to String in the List, a similar looking call behaves kind of odd. The structure is the same as above and I request the index 'a'. I would expect to get an Error telling me that a character doesn't make sense as an index.

But instead I get a result which seems kind of confusing to me:

```
List listOfMap = [['a':'b'], ['a': 'c']]
println listOfMap['a']

>>> [b, c]
```

I tried to find documentation for that but wasn't able to find anything.

Can someone explain the intention of different behavior when using a similar structure. I.e., why doesn't the first example return [b, c] as well to be at least consistent, even though that would probably even more confusing in regards of the standard index operation.

I'd be really thankful for an explanation of the behavior and a reasoning.

Comment: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#gpath_expressions

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if I understood the link correctly, listOfMap['a'] translates to listOfMap.getA() and this gives me all the a-objects from listOfMaps. But why doesn't it work consistently then for the 1? Is it because XML-tags, what GPath expressions were build if I understand correctly don't allow numbers only or tags beginning with numbers?
So I get that numbers as index are usually for place in list, but wouldn't it be more consistent to do it the same way all the time?

Comment: Yeah, but it would break all list access by index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Get by index

Your first example causes a call to Groovy [category](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#categories) `DefaultGroovyMethods.getAt(List<T> list, int index)`. This method returns the item at the specified index.

```
def listOfMap = [
    [1:'b'], 
    [1: 'c']
]

assert listOfMap[0] == listOfMap.getAt(0)
assert listOfMap[0] == [1:'b']

assert listOfMap[1] == listOfMap.getAt(1)
assert listOfMap[1] == [1: 'c']
```

Here's the same method using the second `List<Map>`:

```
def listOfMap = [
    ['a':'b'], 
    ['a': 'c']
]

assert listOfMap[0] == listOfMap.getAt(0)
assert listOfMap[0] == ['a':'b']

assert listOfMap[1] == listOfMap.getAt(1)
assert listOfMap[1] == ['a': 'c']
```

## Get values by property

Your second example calls `DefaultGroovyMethods.getAt(Collection collection, String property)`. This method...

1. Iterates through the Collection
2. Gets all the items which contain the specified property
3. Returns the values of those properties.

The method is written in Java, but the Groovy equivalent is something like this:

```
collection.findAll { it.containsKey(property) }.collect { it.get(property) }
```

## Confirmation

You can witness these methods being called by using a custom category to intercept them:

```
class GetAtTest {
    public static List getAt(Collection self, String property) {
        println 'Got ya! Imitating DefaultGroovyMethods.getAt(Collection, String)...'

        self.findAll { it.containsKey(property) }.collect { it.get(property) }
    }

    public static <T> T getAt(List<T> self, int idx) {
        println 'Got ya! Imitating DefaultGroovyMethods.getAt(List<T>, int)...'

        self.get(idx)
    }
}

use(GetAtTest) {
   println listOfMap[0]
   ...
   println listOfMap['a']
}
```

See https://github.com/apache/incubator-groovy/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Emmanuel Rosa is very good. In addition, the javadoc for the `public static List getAt(Collection coll, String property)` method in DefaultGroovyMethods.java explains it all.

```
    /**
     * Support the subscript operator for Collection.
     * <pre class="groovyTestCase">
     * assert [String, Long, Integer] == ["a",5L,2]["class"]
     * </pre>
     *
     * @param coll     a Collection
     * @param property a String
     * @return a List
     * @since 1.0
     */
     public static List getAt(Collection coll, String property) {
         //...
     }
```